# Subscribe to Nearby services - MessageListener never called

Tags: android, subscribe, google-nearby, message-listener

Subscribe to Nearby services always state that the subscribe is success but the MessageListener never called:

MainActivity.java

```
SubscribeOptions options = new SubscribeOptions.Builder()
            .setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY).build();
    Nearby.Messages.subscribe(mGoogleApiClient, getPendingIntent(), options);
…
private PendingIntent getPendingIntent() {
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(this, BeaconMessageReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

BeaconMessageReceiver.java

public class BeaconMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Nearby.Messages.handleIntent(intent, new MessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFound(Message message) {
            Log.i("BeaconMessageReceiver", "Found message via PendingIntent: " + message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLost(Message message) {
            Log.i("BeaconMessageReceiver", "Lost message via PendingIntent: " + message);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the following into your manifest

```
    <receiver android:name="BeaconMessageReceiver" >
    </receiver>
```